# Android: группы в меню Gmail

Tags: menu, android, drawerlayout, java, android-menu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовано меню с группами в приложении `Gmail`?

1. Это обычный `ListView` где у каждого элемента смотрится, является ли он хедером группы или простой итем?
2. Как они убрали у хедеров `borderLine`?

[image]
<sub>(источник: [addictivetips.com](http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Navigation-Drawer-slide-out-Gmail-for-Android.jpg))</sub>

Comment: не понял сути вопроса - есть задача и десятки способов ее реализации

Comment: @gadfil - я хочу узнать, как это сделано в приложении Gmail

Comment: тогда вопрос к разряду гадания на кофейной гуще, поможет декомпиляция - только зачем ? ну разве что чисто из академического интереса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мой вариант такой: они юзают относительно новый NavigationDrawer со своим макетом. Да, это ListView. Разделители убрали просто поставив в android:dividerHeight значение 0. У ListView может быть заголовок(см метод addHeaderView()). Но возможно это и не список даже, тогда реализовать это значительно проще даже.

Я, например, в похожей ситуации использую StikyListHeaders(кастомный ListView с заголовками, на гитхабе легко находится) в качестве макета для NavigationDrawer-а из android support library. Поэтому реализовать подобное довольно просто.

Comment: У меня получилось сделать только вот так:
 
![gmail group][1]

Вот у них слово `inbox` притянуто к нижнему краю и снизу толстая линия, а сверху она отсутствует. В принципе меня моя реализацию почти устраивает, но вот довести бы её до ума было бы хорошо. Я когда кладу коллекцию в адаптер, помечаю некоторые элементы как `isHeader = true` и вывожу их по особому и отключаю возможность их выбора.
[1]: http://i.imgur.com/yhRskjJ.png

Comment: @ua6xh
хорошо что сами справились и выглядит норм, но звучит как костыль. Ведь еще нужно нажатия с хедеров бы убрать. Поэтому юзать проще StikyListHeaders, а если пунктов мало, то заверстать через Relative/Linear layouts - универсальных менеджеров компоновки. На счет inbox - просто gravity прописан соответствующим образом.